# how to sum amount in multiple json array in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

how to sum amount in multiple json array.
i my table every amount add in json array and i want to sum all amount from json array according to id please help

```
| id   | particulars | client_id

|  140 | [{"amt":"850","ptr":"ITR FEE"}] | 1872
| 1637 | [{"amt":"900","ptr":"ITR RET 2018-19"}] | 1872
```

my query like this:

```
  $fetchfbillamt = $ketObj->runquery("SELECT", "*", "vksoft_fbill", array(), "where client_id=".'1872'."");
if (isset($fetchfbillamt) && is_array($fetchfbillamt) && 
 count($fetchfbillamt) > 0) 
{
  $fbillencodeamt = $fetchfbillamt[0]['particulars'];
  $fbilldecodeamt = json_decode($fbillencodeamt);
  foreach ($fbilldecodeamt as $fbilldecodeamtV) 
  {
     $sumfbillamt +=$fbilldecodeamtV->amt;
  }
echo $sumfbillamt;
}
```

showing output 850

not showing 1750

Comment: You're not tempted to store 'decoded'/normalised data?

Comment: Why not do the summing in the MySQL query instead of PHP? `SELECT SUM(particulars->"$.amt")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written your `foreach` loop on the wrong variable, you should be iterating over `$fetchbillamt` instead. Try this:

```
if (isset($fetchfbillamt) && is_array($fetchfbillamt) && 
 count($fetchfbillamt) > 0) 
{
  foreach ($fetchbillamt as $billamt) {
    $fbillencodeamt = $billamt['particulars'];
    $fbilldecodeamt = json_decode($fbillencodeamt);
    $sumfbillamt += $fbilldecodeamt[0]->amt;
  }
  echo $sumfbillamt;
}
```

Comment: sir showing error  Trying to get property 'amt' of non-object in

Comment: @shivsharma I had a typo which I've corrected (missing `[0]`). Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

You will made the mistake in following place,
      Result Is Multidimensional array but you assign the value in static way.

Try This code,

```
<?php
$fetchfbillamt = array(0=>array('id'=>140,
                     'particulars'=>'[{"amt":"850","ptr":"ITR FEE"}]'),
                      1=>array('id'=>1637,
                    'particulars'=>'[{"amt":"900","ptr":"ITR RET 2018-19"}]'));


$sum = 0;
foreach ($fetchfbillamt as $value){
    $sum += json_decode($value['particulars'],true)[0]['amt'];
}

?>
```

Comment: You should explain what's wrong with his code and how your code fixes it, not just say "try this"

Comment: Hey @Barmar is this okay.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only taking the first row in your line:

`$fbillencodeamt = $fetchfbillamt[0]['particulars'];`

This should actually be in your foreach loop like so:

```
$fetchfbillamt = $ketObj->runquery("SELECT", "*", "vksoft_fbill", array(), "where client_id=".'1872'."");
if (isset($fetchfbillamt) && is_array($fetchfbillamt) && count($fetchfbillamt) > 0) 
{
  foreach ($fetchfbillamt as $fetchedbill) 
  {
      $fbillencodeamt = $fetchedbill['particulars'];
      $fbilldecodeamtV = json_decode($fbillencodeamt);
      $sumfbillamt += $fbilldecodeamtV['amt'];
  }
  echo $sumfbillamt;
}
```

Comment: How is this any different from the answer I posted 10 minutes earlier?

Comment: sir you right.
but showing error  Trying to get property 'amt' of non-object in

Comment: Sorry @Nick, I hadn't seen your answer when I was submitting mine. I guess I took a lot longer to write out the answer.

Comment: @shivsharma if it is not coming through as an object it would probably be $fbillcodeamtV['amt'], I will update my answer now. Nick had the right idea though

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code using the array reduce function. We can create our own custom functions as required and do the operations.

```
$json = array(['amt' =>"850",'ptr'=>"ITR FEE"], ['amt'=>"900",'ptr'=>"ITR FEE"]);

function sum($carry, $item)
{
    $carry += $item['amt'];
    return $carry;
}


var_dump(array_reduce($json, "sum"));
```

Will output `int(1750)`